# Python: how to create sublists through loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a long list containing elements that value from 0 to 100.
What I want to do is find all the positions where my elements take on values [0,2]. Then find out all the positions of the values between 2 and 4, etc up to 98 and 100.

Let's call the list containing the values ''list''. And let's call the resulting list p_x. Where x indicates which interval we are finding the positions of.

I managed to get what i want this way:
p_61 = N.where((list >= 60) & (list <= 62))

My question now is: how do i loop this, so that i get as a result all the p_x's that I want?

Comment: Is this with Numpy? (because you use `where`)

Comment: Yes i used numpy.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

l = list(range(10))

## If you just want the values:
print([(x,y) for (x,y) in itertools.combinations(l, 2) if abs(x-y)==2])

## If you want the positions:
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    for j, y in enumerate(l):
        if j <= i:
            continue
        if abs(x-y) == 2:
            print(i, j)

## If you want them stored in lists in a dictionary:
d = {}
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    for j, y in enumerate(l):
        if j <= i:
            continue
        if abs(x-y) == 2:
            k = 'p_{}'.format(x+1)
            try:
                d[k].append((i,j))
            except KeyError:
                d[k] = [(i,j)]
```